# Is my experiment design and interpretation of treatment effect fine?

Tags: interpretation, experiment-design, treatment-effect

Suppose I want to measure the effect of a treatment in a group of schools (my population). I randomly select a sample of schools and two classes for each school (one treatment and one control). Would it be a problem if I take as outcome the score of a particular exam (for example math)? Suppose exams are identical for the two classes of the same school but different across schools. Would this make my coefficient meaningless?

Comment: What's the purpose of the analysis? What do you want to show/study here?

Comment: A change in the learning environment, e.g. encouraging contacts between students or something like that